# jquery selector: select id of anchor tag within onclick function

Tags: jquery

How can I select id of anchor tag within onclick function with jquery?

```
<a id="123" href="#" onclick="javascript: showDialog( select id of this anchor )"> Click it </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) keyword:

```
<a id="123" href="#" onclick="javascript:showDialog(this.id);">Click it</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

`showDialog(this.id)` but ideally you want to do this unobtrusively and not have inline event handlers.

EDIT: IDs can't start with numbers as DDorward said. Has to be a letter for the start.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is:

```
onclick="showDialog(jQuery(this).attr('id'));"
```

The longer answer is:

1. Don't have ids consisting of just numbers. *ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").* — http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name
2. Don't [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) things if you don't need to, and don't confuse labels with [declaring that an onclick attribute contains JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.1) (rather than another language)
3. Don't use jQuery when a simple property will do (`this.id` is shorter and faster than `jQuery(this).attr('id')`
4. Don't get an id from an element to pass to a function which then gets the element using that id (as `showDialog` presumably does). Pass the element directly: `showDialog(this)`. (You might have to modify `showDialog`).
5. Don't use intrinsic event attributes. [Unobtrusive JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is the way forward.
6. Cancel your events. As it stands, the JS will run and the browser will then follow the link … to the top of the page.
7. When building on a link, point the href attribute at something sensible. If JS isn't available then a user probably doesn't expect the link to send them to the top of the page instead. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build).

Answer (score 3):

Within the event handler `this` refers to the element, so `this.id` gives you the id of the element.

Usually you would add the event handler with code rather than have an inline handler. You would also want to prevent the default action of the link, which is to go to the address of the `href` attribute. In this case it would jump to the bookmark `#`, which causes the page to scroll to the top.

```
$(function(){
  $('#123').click(function(e){
    showDialog(this.id);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```